# Java, Count number of students who take the same course as a method in Student Class

Tags: java, class, methods, count

I'm trying to write a java class called "Student" which have an attribute called "courseCode" in which the user can input any course code he wants.

*I don't know the course codes, I'll let the user enter any course code he wants

Example:

```
Student st1 = new Student("William", .., .., "CS 124");



Student st2 = new Student("James", .., .., "AU 487");



Student st3 = new Student("David", .., .., "CS 124");



Student st4 = new Student("Richard", .., .., "CS 124");



Student st5 = new Student("John", .., .., "AU 487");
```

In the above example, 3 students registered in course "CS 124" and 2 students registered in "AU 487"

I want to create a static method in Student class itself that can be given a **course code** as an input and returns the **number of students registered in the same course.**

Example:

```
Student.numberOfStudentsInCourse("AU 487");
```

*Output: 2*

```
Student.numberOfStudentsInCourse("CS 124");
```

*Output: 3*

I hope I could make it clear to you.
Thanks for your help

Comment: *I want to create a static method in Student class itself* Is this specifically part of your assignment, or is it your own concept?

Comment: chrylis, actually my assignment's question gave a specific course code and just asked to count the number of students enrolled in that course, which is easy actually, I only need one static variable with the couse code name and just increment it with each constructor that is made.
But I always like to be different and do the assignments with a more creative way.

Comment: Okay. I want to point out that while you are doing a good job of thinking of alternate solutions, this approach (_static state_) has a _lot_ of problems and is generally not suitable for most programs. In particular, it is nearly impossible to test, and it is impossible to segregate different groups of students (e.g., for different schools). Instead, it is generally better to create a method (potentially a static method) that accepts a `Collection<Student>` and the course code.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I can't understand those high level concepts yet. And of course I can't ask you to explain them in detail because those concepts need more than just a comment to be explained. But let me clarify why I wanted to make that method as static. I just wanted to call the method using the class name "Student" (e.g. Student.numberOfStudentsInClass();) without having to create an object to call that method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one suggestion, at a high level:

- In Student class, create a static HashMap<String, Integer>, key is course code, value is counter of students registered for the course.
- In the constructor of Student, increment count for the respected course.
- In numberOfStudentsInCourse(), return the count for matching course.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, your method will need to have a parameter of List<String> or something similar to tell the method which student objects it needs to be looking through.

```
public static int numberOfStudentsInCourse(List<Student> students, String courseCode) {
   int count = 0;
   for(Student student : students)
      if(student.getCourseCode().equals(courseCode))
         count++;
   return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to show you a java >=8 approach

You can use the following code to create a Map from courseCode to list of Students with the courseCode

```
Map<String, Long> courseToCountMap = students.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> n.getCourseCode(), Collectors.counting()));

courseToCountMap.entrySet().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue()));
```

My Student class

```
class Student {
    String courseCode;

    public Student(String courseCode) {
        super();
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
    }

    public String getCourseCode() {
        return courseCode;
    }

    public void setCourseCode(String courseCode) {
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
    }

}
```